# Words to describe a submarine arriving in port

Tags: verbs

What verb should be used to describe a submarine arrival at a port or dock?  A boat moors, a plane lands, a submarine...

Comment: A submarine docks.  Or moors, if it ties up to a buoy or some such.  In a harbor a submarine (unless it's infiltrating the enemy) travels on the surface like any other boat.

Comment: @HotLicks +1 Came here to write that exact term--docks :)

Comment: I've changed "to" to "at". I believe your use of preposition is incorrect.

Comment: Also, the more usual expression is "arriving IN port".

Comment: Many thanks for correcting my prepositions.  I speak French, Spanish and English and my prepositions tend to get jumble up between the three languages.

Answer (score 3):

A submarine is a type of boat. In fact, they call submarines boats. And when submarines arrive at port its always on the surface, just like a boat, so I would use whatever words are appropriate for the same action of a non-submarine boat.

> The noun submarine evolved as a shortened form of submarine boat;[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine)
>   by naval tradition, submarines are usually referred to as "boats"
>   rather than as "ships", regardless of their size (boat is usually
>   reserved for seagoing vessels of relatively small size). [Submarine-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine)

Answer (score 1):

A submarine **returns to its berth**.  The [WWI Bookshelf at Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/World_War_I_(Bookshelf)) has some good accounts of submarines in original English and translated from the German by contemporary English-speakers.  The 1914-1918 war saw the first major use of submarines as a weapon, and is therefore where the original terminology developed.

In a general sense, a submarine is just another boat.  However, if it's going to be reloaded with torpedoes and other specialized supplies, it has to go to its own special place, which it can share with other submarines in the same way that sailors on different watches might share a berth. So the best term depends on what kind of port or dock it's approaching, and why.

BTW, there's not a lot of specific description in the e-books about tying up submarines at docks, wharfs, and the like.  The authors probably didn't think that these would be interesting to most readers :)